# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while connecting mysql from mysql.connector

Tags: mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

I was encountering "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" for simply importing mysql.connector from mysql-connector-python.
python version 3.6

Answer (score 1):

searching web all I figured out that the import statement must be in front of all the import statements and rest worked .

original link here :
https://www.programmersought.com/article/47925970411/